# In how many permutations of $\lbrace a,b,c,d,e \rbrace$ a comes before e and e come after c?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

In how many permutations of $\lbrace a,b,c,d,e \rbrace$ $a$ comes before $e$ and $e$ come after $c$?

I know that the answer is $\frac{5!}{3}$ but I don't understand why?

My approach is:

In half of the permutations, $a$ comes before $e$, and then we should determine the order of $e$ and $c$.  Then $c$ may be between $a$ and $e$ or $c$ comes after $e$ or $c$ comes before $a$ and $\frac{2}{3}$ of possible situations are just as we wanted. so $\frac{2}{3} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{3}$ of all permutations is the answer.

Is my approach correct? and is there another way to solve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, your approach is correct.

Comment: thank you, sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct! Another way is just choose the $3$ spots in which you are placing $a,e,c$ in $\binom{5}{3}\cdot 2$ ways because you pick the $3$ spots and then you can have either "ac" or "ca", and then multiply by $2!$ to know what to do with $b,d$ so $$\binom{5}{3}2!\cdot 2=\frac{5!}{3!}\cdot 2=\frac{5!}{3}.$$

Comment: ah yeah! Gracias!

Comment: @ArsalanHasanvand De nada, you are welcome!